# JavaScript Not Working properly in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am pretty new to JavaScript and got stuck at one point:
I am using asp control fileupload to upload some files and store them to database, i am using asp repeater control to show all the docs in database in front end and have associated a html checkbox to every doc:
The problem is when i check or uncheck the checkbox, the delete button enables/disables accordingly, but when i click the "Select All" button where i am calling both functions - to check all checkboxes and to enable button, somehow the delete button is not getting enabled..Please help.

Here is JavaScript Code to enable delete button:-

```
function EnableButton() {
            var rpt = document.getElementById('<%= rptWordDoc.ClientID  %>');
            var chkbx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var x = document.getElementById("btnDelWordDoc");
            for (i = 0; i <= chkbx.length; i++) {
                var id = "rptWordDoc_chkWordDoc_" + i
                var y = document.getElementById(id);
                if (y == null) {
                    break;
                }
                if (y.checked == true) {
                    x.disabled = false;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    x.disabled = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

This is how i am calling the function:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelectAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" OnClientClick="fnSelectAll(); JavaScript:EnableButton();" />
```

Through Checkbox:-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkWordDoc" runat="server" onclick="JavaScript:EnableButton();" />
```

Comment: `"fnSelectAll(); JavaScript:EnableButton();"` should be `"JavaScript:fnSelectAll(); EnableButton();"`

Comment: also note that the `javascript:` is not needed unless you also have vbscript on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause:
Actually i was using asp: button control for Select All & Clear All features and thus it was posting back to the server and setting back the value of delete button enabled attribute to false.

I added a html control instead of asp button for Select All & clear all buttons and didn't added runat=server attribute since no server side event was required.

Thanks for your suggestions..
Cheers..:)

Answer (score 0):

You called two functions `fnSelectAll();`  and `JavaScript:EnableButton();` may be second is not executed after executing the first one.

Comment: No, I have debugged the code, it is calling both functions. I have checked the property of button too..before exit it is setting: x.disabled = false;